# Strange behaviour of lambda function inside parallel block in openmp c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, scope, openmp

I've started to learn OpenMP for couple of days. I have come across this error that I can't resolve.
I've defined a lambda function `f` which captures local variable `s`. Now, If I change the variable `s` (a private variable to each thread) inside the parallel for loop then the function `f` doesn't reflect the change in its output and gives always `0`. I can understand that I'm doing some error in scoping but unable to find the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    using namespace std;
    double s;
    auto f =[&]{return s;};

#pragma omp parallel for private(s)
        for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        s = 5+i;
        double a1 = f();
#pragma omp critical
        cout << a1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And if I define the lambda inside the parallel for loop, it actually works and returns the proper value of `s` and not `0`, i.e.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(s)
            for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            s = 5+i;
            double a1 = [&]{return s;}();
    #pragma omp critical
            cout << a1 << endl;
        }
```

My guess is that the lambda function and the captured variable needs to be in the same scope.
**How to fix this if the lambda function is defined outside the parallel block?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP, but my guess is `private(s)` means "give each thread its own copy of `s`". But `f` has captured the "real" `s`, the one declared outside the loop. It doesn't know about those private copies. I predict you will have the same behavior if you write `double& s_ref = s;` where `f` is declared, and use `s_ref` instead of `f()`. A lambda is a red herring.

Comment: Re: how to fix it. Hard to say without knowing what you are ultimately trying to achieve. One way would be to have the lambda take `s` as a parameter, rather than capturing it. Then each thread would pass its own local copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have also thought about that, taking `s` as a parameter. That will surely work.

Comment: `private` directive declares data to have a separate copy in the memory of each thread. In other words each thread has its own copy of `s`. What you do to `s` isn't seen in the outer scope.  If you want to share the value of `s` remove the `private` directive.

Comment: @WBuck I originally had this problem with parallel omp for loop. I wanted each of the threads to get their own copy of `s`. I think I should change the code for loop in it

Comment: @Galilean If you want to share data between `threads`'s you can. Just make sure you `synchronize` access to the variable using a `mutex` or some other `synchronization` mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with multiple `s` variables. The `s` variable(s) within the `parallel region`(s) and the `s` variable declared in the outer scope.

The `private` directive declares data to have a separate copy in the memory of each thread. So, each thread will have its own copy of `s` which resides in a different memory location than the `s` declared in the outer scope `double s;`.

When you change the value of `s` in the `parallel region` you're only changing the thread local copy of `s`.

The value of `s` in your outer scope (which you are capturing by `ref` in a `lambda`) would not be changed. The outer `s` is located in a different memory location.

Side note, you should be initializing your outer `s` variable: `double s{ 0 };`.

```
// This value of x will remain unchanged.
int x = 5;

#pragma omp parallel private( x )
{
    // What happens in the `parallel block` stays in the
    // in the `parallel block`. In other words, incrementing this
    // local value of x will not change the value of x declared in the
    // outer scope. That's because this `parallel block` has its own copy of x.
    x++;      
}


// This value of x will change.
int x = 5;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    // The x variable is now shared between each thread. What you
    // do to x here changes the value of x in the outer scope.
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        x++;         
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this quite a lot recently that people are using the capture as a way to "work on" some data. Although you can do this, capturing is more generally used to access specific instances of objects (a bit like binding).

I think it is "better" (perhaps more generic), if you can pass your data as a parameter, or if you want to share the data you can pass-by-reference:

So instead of:

```
auto f =[&]{return s;};
```

You can do:

```
auto f =[](double dbl){return dbl;}; // by copy
auto f =[](double &dbl){return dbl;}; // or by ref
```

And then use like:

```
s = 5+i;
double a1 = f(s); // Here pass "s" into the lambda
```

So, I am not saying don't use the capture, sometimes this is good, but it just looks like you are better off here using a parameter.